# Add space every 3 characters in span

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have some span like this :

```
<span class="example">12345678</span>
<span class="example">123456</span>
```

But I want my number to be displayed like this :
`12345678 -> 12 345 678`
`123456 -> 123 456`

Is it possible in CSS or only in JS/jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.  You will have to use JS/jQuery.

Comment: @mplungjan Well, I don't think so.

Comment: Because I don't have to _vote_. And I didn't say this answer is good or not! I meant to say not every answer should provide code.

Comment: The answer is correct, as illustrated by the duplicate @mplungjan provided.  If you don't want to accept it, that is up to you.  However, I don't see why you wouldn't.